# base64 raster <image> in SVG is washed out in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, vector

I have a SVG that contains raster images that are encoded via base64

I have tested in safari and firefox, the images look fine.But in chrome they are faded or washed out.

Using chrome 48, i have never encountered somthing like this so i really am lost for how to provide information

Vector was generated by sketch

[image]

Comment: What are we looking at? Which one is Chrome?  An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: both are chrome, but its a normal image in another browser

Comment: Post a working SVG that shows the problem. It's not a known problem, so can't really be diagnosed from a screenshot.